# Vim : getline and non ascii character

Tags: character-encoding, vi

I use a single function (that a create) to know if the character next to the current cursor position is a space

```
function Test_caractere_suivant_espace()
"Test si le caractère suivant est une espace"
    let position = getcurpos()
    let ligne = getline(position[1])
    let car_suivant = ligne[position[2]]
    if car_suivant == ' '
        return 1
    else 
        return 0
endfunction
```

It work well… but only with Ascii characters, not with not Ascii characters in UTF-8.

Of course, I could try the value of the two first bits of the current character, but is there anyway to have UTF-8 characters in the array returned by `getline` and not a list of one-byte values?

## A pist of solution

DJMcMayhem suggest a solution using

```
 let ligne = split(getline(position[1]), '\zs')
```

But there is still a problem to determine the next character.
Here is the new version of the function

```
function Test_caractere_suivant_espace()
"Test si le caractère suivant est une espace"
    let position = getcurpos()
    let ligne = split(getline(position[1]), '\zs')
    let car_suivant = ligne[position[2]]
    echom car_suivant
    if car_suivant == ' '
        return 1
    else 
        return 0
endfunction
```

In this line

```
α α α α α α α α α α
```

If I call the function in the before last α, I get

```
Error detected while processing function LB_content[2]..Test_caractere_suivant_espace:
line    4:
E684: list index out of range: 25
E15: Invalid expression: ligne[position[2]]
line    5:
E121: Undefined variable: car_suivant
E15: Invalid expression: car_suivant
line    6:
E121: Undefined variable: car_suivant
E15: Invalid expression: car_suivant == ' '
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no way to do this that I am aware of. `:h getline` mentions nothing about encoding options, and from [this vim mailing list I found](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/How-to-get-the-charactor-under-cursor-in-vimscript-td1181648.html), it seems like this problem has been around for a while with no fix.

*However*, I did figure out a hacky workaround. Instead of working with strings, you can work with a list of characters instead. Indexing into that will give you whole characters instead of individual bytes. Try this:

```
    let ligne = split(getline(position[1]), '\zs')
```

Comment: Thanks for this quick answer. Unfortunatly, it seems that is does not work

Comment: I think that is because I need to adapt the position of the current character. `let car_suivant = ligne[position[2]]`

Comment: @Maïeul Can you clarify what exactly isn't working? `split(getline(n), '\zs')` returns a list of characters, and indexing it to non-ASCII positions still returns single non-ASCII characters, so I'm not sure what isn't working.

Comment: the return of the main `Test_caractere_suivant_espace()` is not working.  I will add a comment to my main question to explain more.

Comment: @Maïeul The updated code you have provided doesn't use my solution. You aren't calling `split` anywhere. When I update line 4 to the line I recommended, it works perfectly fine for me.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. I have any way changed my addendum. Your solution didn't work with long lines.

Comment: @Maïeul OK, no offense but you asked `is there anyway to have UTF-8 characters in the array returned by getline and not a list of one-byte values?`, which I have answered. The reason your code is not working is because the rest of it is buggy, not because my solution is wrong. `getcurpos` tells you what *byte* your cursor is on, not which character, so you are trying to read the 29'th character on a line that only contains 20 characters. Try doing `position[4]` instead, but keep in mind that this will also cause issues if the cursor is on the last character in the line.

Comment: Yes, as I explained in my comment to your answer, "I think that is because I need to adapt the position of the current character". So yes, the rest is buggy, but how could. My problem is basic: how to get the next character after the cursor.  Maybe my title was wrong, but in my introduction, I exposed my problem.